# Java - How to run a few shell/bat files at once or in sequence from a folder

Tags: java, shell, batch-file, sh

im having a little trouble finding out how to execute a few script files in Java, now I can run a single file specifying it's directory.

The purpose of this project is to be able to execute various script files from a folder in sequence (or at once).

Could you guys help me out?

Im using ProcessBuilder / RuntimeExec

**1. ProcessBuilder**

```
String[] commandFile = new String[]{"FILE DIRECTORY"};
ProcessBuilder processb = new ProcessBuilder(commandFile);
Process p = processb.start();
```

**2. RuntimeExec**

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("FILE DIRECTORY OR COMMAND");
```

Comment: Im using ProcessBuilder / RuntimeExec

Answer (score 1):

You proboably need to manually look what Files are in the Folder via https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#list() or something similar, then loop through the files and then use one of the 2 Methods you wrote in you question to execute each file.